# How to delete a resource type in openstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I created a resource type with random_string.py.
https://github.com/openstack/heat/blob/master/heat/engine/resources/openstack/heat/random_string.py

```
# heat resource-type-list
+------------------------------------------+
| resource_type                            |
+------------------------------------------+
| CN::CLOUD::RandomString                   |
```

But I don't know how to delete it. Please help provide the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% certain but this is as far as I know.

Heat resource_types is a part of a [heat/provider](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat/Providers) plugin, so in order to 'delete' the resource type you need to 'unistall' the pluging. In your case I thing this particular resource type is an example used for development purposes.

You can also find the already implement resources types [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/)

Comment: Do you mean I need to uninstall heat? I am afraid that's not a good idea as heat itself is a component that I need. Thanks.

Comment: No, I did not mean to unistall heat. I mean to unistall the 'provider' plugin